# Display MoveIt Collison Objects in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, moveit, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i display collision objects i added to my MoveIt planning scene in Gazebo?
I added them like:

```
# publish a demo scene
scene = PlanningSceneInterface()
p = PoseStamped()
p.header.frame_id = robot.get_planning_frame()

# add a box
p.pose.position.x = 0.7
p.pose.position.y = -0.08
p.pose.position.z = 0.1
scene.add_box("box", p, (0.15, 0.15, 0.15))
```

They are all diplayed well in MoveIt but not in Gazebo right now. The robot is displayed in gazebo as well. Im running ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256358/display-moveit-collison-objects-in-gazebo/) by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:
Without *spawning* them yourself (like you would with some other arbitrary (urdf) model) I don't think this is possible (ie: I know of no automation in place that will do this for you).

**Comment by [Sai kiran](https://answers.ros.org/users/31447/sai-kiran/) on 2017-09-05**:
Hi

For me also, same problem.

Did you find any way for this, to show all objects in Gazebo what ever there in Moveit.

If you find, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't "display moveit objects in gazebo". That's the wrong way around.

If you add them to gazebo they are (or should be in any case) physical objects in the real world, with gravity and other forces acting on them.
`CollisionObjects` in MoveIt do not change their position on their own and they are allowed to collide with the robot - MoveIt does not prohibit this, it just tells you your robot is in collision in this case.

So you might want to spawn objects in gazebo (i.e. the real world) and forward their poses to MoveIt (as a magical pose estimation module) to display them in RViz. But not the other way around.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1